# Page_Load get the button sender

Tags: asp.net, sender

Hi is possible to get the button sender that generates the event click?

if i check the sender in the page_load i view null

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that you check it in `page_load`? You should check the `sender` in the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

In the click event handler for the button it will be the source of the click (`e.Source`).

Post back events occur after the page load, so it is not possible to determine in the page load event handler.

See the [asp.net page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more information